# Remove duplicates from NESTED array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have an array of objects like below, which inside of it has another array of objects which has duplicate **verticalName** values that need to be removed in order to be displayed on the page.

```
 "landingPages": [
        {
          "programmes": [
            {
              "progName": "Programme 1",
              "verticals": [
                {
                  "id": "8",
                  "verticalName": "Law and Criminology"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "programmes": [
            {
              "progName": "Programme 2",
              "verticals": [
                {
                  "id": "1",
                  "verticalName": "Psychology and Sociology"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "programmes": [
            {
              "progName": "Programme 3",
              "verticals": [
                {
                  "id": "3",
                  "verticalName": "Computing and IT"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "programmes": [
            {
              "progName": "Programme 4",
              "verticals": [
                {
                  "id": "1",
                  "verticalName": "Psychology and Sociology"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "progName": "Programme 5",
              "verticals": [
                {
                  "id": "3",
                  "verticalName": "Computing and IT"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "progName": "Programme 6",
              "verticals": [
                {
                  "id": "2",
                  "verticalName": "Business and Management"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "progName": "Programme 7",
              "verticals": [
                {
                  "id": "3",
                  "verticalName": "Computing and IT"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "progName": "Programme 8",
              "verticals": [
                {
                  "id": "3",
                  "verticalName": "Computing and IT"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

I have tried couple of solutions, some of the did not work but one did, which I copy/pasted below. I've managed to store all of them inside of one array of objects, it's just that the code to me looks really bad. I am trying to find a cleaner solution to this problem. Here is my solution and I would like to see how does it compare to your solutions maybe, and if you could give me some feedback that would be amazing.

```
    let known = {}
    let noduplicates = programmes.map((subarray) => {
        const newarrays = []
        subarray.verticals.forEach((item) => {
            if (
                !known.hasOwnProperty(item.verticalName) &&
                (known[item.verticalName] = true)
            ) {
                newararys.push(item)
            } else {
                console.log('test')
            }
        })
        console.log(newarrays)
        return newarrays
    })
    const fil = filtered.filter((item) => item.length)
    const singleArr = fil.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [])
    console.log(singleArr)
```

What I am trying to get is something like this, basically, just all the objects that were found inside of **verticals** array, but - without duplicates:

```
[
   {id: "1", verticalName: "Psychology and Sociology"}, 
   {id: "3", verticalName: "Computing and IT"}, 
   {id: "2", verticalName: "Business and Management"}
]
```

Cheers everyone!

Comment: define duplicate. verticals? then which progName stay? or does progName does not matter? How you want your final array to look like?

Comment: Hi, I updated the question. It's the verticalName inside key inside of the nested "vertical" array.  It doesn't matter, I just need to store all the non duplicate values inside of one array of objects.

Answer (score 2):

You may use **set** for this use case which lets you store unique values of any type.

```js
const data = [
        {
          "programmes": [
            {
              "progName": "Programme 1",
              "verticals": [
                {
                  "id": "8",
                  "verticalName": "Law and Criminology"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "programmes": [
            {
              "progName": "Programme 2",
              "verticals": [
                {
                  "id": "1",
                  "verticalName": "Psychology and Sociology"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "programmes": [
            {
              "progName": "Programme 3",
              "verticals": [
                {
                  "id": "3",
                  "verticalName": "Computing and IT"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "programmes": [
            {
              "progName": "Programme 4",
              "verticals": [
                {
                  "id": "1",
                  "verticalName": "Psychology and Sociology"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "progName": "Programme 5",
              "verticals": [
                {
                  "id": "3",
                  "verticalName": "Computing and IT"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "progName": "Programme 6",
              "verticals": [
                {
                  "id": "2",
                  "verticalName": "Business and Management"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "progName": "Programme 7",
              "verticals": [
                {
                  "id": "3",
                  "verticalName": "Computing and IT"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "progName": "Programme 8",
              "verticals": [
                {
                  "id": "3",
                  "verticalName": "Computing and IT"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ];
      
      const seen = new Set();
      const filteredArr = data.filter(el => {
        const verticalName = el.programmes[0].verticals[0].verticalName;
        const duplicate = seen.has(verticalName);
        seen.add(verticalName);
        return !duplicate;
      });

      console.log(filteredArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve it by pure ES6 functions, I'll decompose, but you can have it all in one line :)

first, you need to retrieve all verticalNames

```
const allVerticalNames = landingPages.map(lp => lp.programmes.map(p => p.verticals))
```

You'll have plenty arrays or arrays, so we need to flatten all of this

```
const flattened = allVerticalNames.flat(2)
```

At this point you have all your verticalNames, but not uniq. To do that, we should convert it to a Set, Map or easier, an Object

```
const keyValuePairs = flattened.map(v => [v.id, v.verticalName]); // We transform to a pair key / value
const uniq = Object.fromEntries(keyValuePairs)
```

At this point you have an object like `{1: "Psychology and Sociology", 2: "Business and Management", 3: "Computing and IT", 8: "Law and Criminology"}`
So if you want to have it back to the way in exemple, you move it back to an array!

```
const final = Object.entries(uniq).map(([id, verticalName]) => ({id, verticalName}))
```

And that's it!

All in one line?

```
const final = Object.entries(Object.fromEntries(landingPages.map(lp => lp.programmes.map(p => p.verticals)).flat(2).map(v => [v.id, v.verticalName]))).map(([id, verticalName]) => ({id, verticalName}))
```

Comment: Based on the expected outcome in the question, I think OP just wants duplicates eliminated from the nested array, the unique values don't necessarily depend on the values of verticals at the root level of the `landingPages` array. Your answer is great tbh, but the output includes `Law and Criminology` which is not in the expected outcome.

Comment: I tought we needed all the uniq values across all programs. We can adapt the logic very easily to remove duplicate in each program only thought ;)

Comment: Cleanest solution to be honest, and a great explanation of each step

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, we need to remove the `verticalNames` from the nested `programmes` array.

```js
const landingPages = [
  {
    programmes: [
      {
        progName: 'Programme 1',
        verticals: [
          {
            id: '8',
            verticalName: 'Law and Criminology',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    programmes: [
      {
        progName: 'Programme 2',
        verticals: [
          {
            id: '1',
            verticalName: 'Psychology and Sociology',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    programmes: [
      {
        progName: 'Programme 3',
        verticals: [
          {
            id: '3',
            verticalName: 'Computing and IT',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    programmes: [
      {
        progName: 'Programme 4',
        verticals: [
          {
            id: '1',
            verticalName: 'Psychology and Sociology',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        progName: 'Programme 5',
        verticals: [
          {
            id: '3',
            verticalName: 'Computing and IT',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        progName: 'Programme 6',
        verticals: [
          {
            id: '2',
            verticalName: 'Business and Management',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        progName: 'Programme 7',
        verticals: [
          {
            id: '3',
            verticalName: 'Computing and IT',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        progName: 'Programme 8',
        verticals: [
          {
            id: '3',
            verticalName: 'Computing and IT',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]

let page = landingPages.find(page => page.programmes.length > 1);
const uniqueprogrammes = new Set();

const uniqueverticals = page.programmes.map(p => {
  const vn = p.verticals[0].verticalName;
  if (!uniqueprogrammes.has(vn)) {
    uniqueprogrammes.add(vn);
    return p.verticals[0];
  }
}).filter(v => !!v);

console.log(uniqueverticals);
```

**UPDATE:**

Updated code snippet based on the expected outcome in the question.

The idea is to first find the nested array of programmes which is done by filtering the `landingPages` object based on the `.length`

```
let page = landingPages.find(page => page.programmes.length > 1);
```

Then, we create a set to keep a track of all the unique programmes from this nested array,

```
const uniqueprogrammes = new Set();
```

Next, we `map` through the nested array and find all the verticals that are not a part of the `uniqueprogrammes` set,

```
const uniqueverticals = page.programmes.map(p => {
  const vn = p.verticals[0].verticalName;
  if (!uniqueprogrammes.has(vn)) {
    uniqueprogrammes.add(vn);
    return p.verticals[0];
  }
})
```

However, this will gives us an output like the following,

```
[
  { id: '1', verticalName: 'Psychology and Sociology' },
  { id: '3', verticalName: 'Computing and IT' },
  { id: '2', verticalName: 'Business and Management' },
  undefined,
  undefined
]
```

so (lastly), we need to `filter` out the falsy values with,

```
.filter(v => !!v);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use **loadash** to flatter and then remove duplicates.

var arrayWithDuplicatesRemoved=*.flattenDeep(landingPages);



arrayWithDuplicatesRemoved = arrayWithDuplicatesRemoved*.uniqBy(data, function (e) {return e.verticalName;});

Comment: Suggesting external libs for basic JS functionality is not that ideal.

Comment: @BrainFooLong the question is tagged with `lodash`