# Remove duplicates from inner array of array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, duplicates

Here is my array. How can I remove duplicates in this type of structure? When I map over arr I get the values of each array nested in each object. And I want to filter the duplicated values.
current output: bye hello hello
The expected output should be: bye hello

```
[

    {
        arr: ['']
        val: "string"
    }
    {
        arr: ['bye', 'hello']
        val: "string"
    }
    {
        arr: ['hello']
        val: "string"
    }

]
    
    
myArray.map(item => item.arr.map((el, index) =>
    <p key={index}>{el}</p>       
))
```

Comment: [you can go through this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67487238/remove-duplicates-from-nested-array-of-objects) I think it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply manage an array to filter what you want to display :

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

const App = () => {
  const data = [
    {
      arr: [''],
      val: 'string',
    },
    {
      arr: ['bye', 'hello'],
      val: 'string',
    },
    {
      arr: ['hello'],
      val: 'string',
    },
  ];

  const buildData = () => {
    const passedValues = [];
    return data.map((item) => {
      return item.arr.map((el) => {
        if (!passedValues.includes(el)) {
          passedValues.push(el);
          return <div>{el}</div>;
        }
      });
    });
  };

  return <div>{buildData()}</div>;
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here is [the repro on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-grg5u3).

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help you:

```
const filteredArray = useMemo(() => {
   const used = []
   
   return myArray.map(sub => {
      return { ...sub, arr:sub.arr.map(el 
    => {
      if(used.includes(el) return null
      used.push(el)
      return el
    }}
   })
}, deps)
```

And then in JSX:

```
filteredArray.map(() => ...)
```

Comment: *I hope it will help you* is considered fluff, and should be left out of questions and answers. What **should** be included is an explanation of what your answer does. Don't make the OP and future readers figure out your code (or more likely copy/paste without understanding it).

Comment: I can give explanation personally for you. I write on my phone. And it is not simple

Comment: It's got to be easier to write a paragraph of explanation on a phone than it is to code...

Comment: Ok I understand will improve my answers in the future

Answer (score 0):

All of these answer are good...I think @vitaliyirtlach has the best as its the  closest to React.

I'll just put it out there that you can also loop through `myArray`, remove the duplicates with `Set` and then place them in an array that you can loop over:

```
    const myArray = [
    
        {
            arr: [''],
            val: "string"
        },
        {
            arr: ['bye', 'hello'],
            val: "string"
        },
        {
            arr: ['hello'],
            val: "string"
        }
    
    ]
    
    const removeDupes = () => {
      const newArr = []
      myArray.map(item => item.arr.map((el, index) =>
        newArr.push(el)     
      ))
      return [...new Set(newArr)]
    }
    
    const loopArray = removeDupes();
    
    console.log(loopArray)// logs ["","bye","hello"]

    loopArray.map((el, index) =>
      <p key={index}>{el}</p>
    ))
```