# Remove duplicates from multi-level array of objects

Tags: typescript

I have this array of objects and I am wanting to filter out where `myDatas.items.flaggedItem` is not `null` and at the same time remove the duplicates where `myDatas.items.id` are the same. So in this instance I would only expect 2 to be returned

```
"myDatas":[
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "items":[
       {
         "id": "idOne",
         "flaggedItem": null,
       },
       {
         "id": "idTwo",
         "flaggedItem": 1,
       },
   },
   {
     "id": "id2",
     "items":[
       {
         "id": "idTwo",
         "flaggedItem": 1,
       },
       {
         "id": "idOne",
         "flaggedItem": 2,
       },
   }
]
```

I have this, but unable to find a good way to remove the duplicates. This accomplishes the first part where I am pulling only items where `myDatas.items.flaggedItem` is not `null`, but does not remove the duplicates.

```
  let test1 = myDatas
    ?.map(myData => {
      let test2 = myData.items?.filter(
        items => items.flaggedItem || items.flaggedItem === 0
      );
      return { ...myData, items: test2 };
    });
```

Comment: You're going to have to concatenate the `items` arrays together to deduplicate it easily...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicates from NESTED array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67487238/remove-duplicates-from-nested-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to filter out the duplicate data is by keeping a duplicates map:

```js
const myData = [
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "idOne",
        "flaggedItem": null,
      },
      {
        "id": "idTwo",
        "flaggedItem": 1,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "idTwo",
        "flaggedItem": 1,
      },
      {
        "id": "idOne",
        "flaggedItem": 2,
      },
    ],
  },
];

const duplicates = {};

const dedupedData = myData.map((element) => {
  const items = element.items.filter((item) => {
    if (!item.flaggedItem && item.flaggedItem !== 0) return false;

    if (duplicates[item.id]) return false;
    duplicates[item.id] = true;

    return true;
  });

  return {
    ...element,
    items,
  };
});

console.log(dedupedData);
```